# Getting chromecast sample code to run

Tags: google-cast

I have found no joy in getting any of the sample programs for Chrome to connect to my Chromecasts.
The Chromecasts have been registered and I am able to browse to their IP address port 9222 successfully.
Both the Chrome browser and Beta extension are up to date.
I have tried the CastHelloVideo-Chrome, CastMedia-Chrome and Cast-Tictactoe-Chrome and all fail to connect.  The developer console shows a pair of errors:
GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED 
and
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

When testing our own code we get an error when calling requestSession but the message returned  by Chrome.cast.Error is useless since the function and variable names have been obscured.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a difficult time testing the examples for Chrome. I decided to use Chrome to test because debugging JavaScript is so much quicker than going directly to Android. I spent hours trying to figure out why I keep getting the error message  **GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED and Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')** if I run it from my PC but not when I run it from an example website at  http://www.videws.com/eureka/helloVideos/ provided by one of the Cast developers at Google. I keep reading/trying different combinations from  his readme note in the example until it dawned on me what he meant by "Put all files on your own server" instead of "computer".

I created a public weblink on my Google Drive, make the folder public and copied all the files there. When go to Google drive on the web, preview the example (index.html), the example runs beautifully. I tried tic-tac-toe. It also runs.

So the answer is you need to run it off a website -- not from a local file in your computer (ctrl-O in Chrome)

I hope this will help you going with Cast.

Danh

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get connected, but from Android. Many steps will be the same though.
I tested this:  https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android  It let's you speak into the phone, and what you say appears on the TV/Chromecast.  I didn't install the formal sender app, but I was able to load the TicTac Toe from the receiver as well.  So i have seen them both on my CC.

I couldn't connect until I properly setup the RECEIVER APPLICATION.  You didn't mention it.

What I did from where I think you are at.. I just double checked my receiver app settings.

1. File copy the receiver.hml file provided in the sample sender app. Place it in a public dropbox folder.  copy that public link to my clipboard.
2. Go back to where you registered your Chromecast device(s). https://cast.google.com/publish -Add An Application.  I called mine :  ReceiverSimple
3. Edit the app you just created, and for the URL field: paste in that public link. For you, set the platform to Chrome.   It did not seem to matter whether or not i included the package name, so try leaving it blank.
4. Save It. Now COPY to clipboard the ApplicationID for the receiver you just created.
5. Open the provided sender app source code, and find where it's using APP_ID (hopefully R.Strings or equivalent in chrome ) Paste that App ID in. That will tell your client to use your receiver app, (and therefore, load that receiver.html file into the chrome cast screen).

also try a chrome cast reboot as another means of sanity checking.

I think you're close.

Comment: Where can I find the HTML code of this sample Receiver?